# Reference to appDelegate when different UIApplicationMain

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, xctest

In my main.swift file I've got 2 different main applications, for testing and for app:

```
if NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") != nil {
    UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegateTesting))
} else {
    UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
}
```

In app I'm accesing to AppDelegate:

```
extension UIApplication {
    static func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
}
```

so when doing XCTests, it doesn't work. How to fix it?
I don't want to duplicate code. Maybe mock it or create protocol for UIApplication. 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm doing iOS app development since 2009 and I have never seen two different `AppDelegates` in one app. I think you are doing something wrong. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @dasdom, I always use 2 AppDelegates: http://qualitycoding.org/app-delegate-for-tests/. The challenge the OP faces is how to implement `getAppDelegate` with Swift's strict type rules.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll show you how to do it. Then, I'll argue that you probably shouldn't.

**How to do it:**

Interfaces are used throughout Java to support testing. In Objective-C, protocols weren't required to substitute different implementations. But in Swift, protocols are the way to support multiple implementations (test and production) of the same interface.

```
protocol AppDelegateProtocol {
    // whatever you need
}

extension UIApplication {
    static func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegateProtocol {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegateProtocol
    }
}
```

Of course, both AppDelegate and AppDelegateTesting must conform to AppDelegateProtocol.

**Why you probably shouldn't do it:**

The purpose of the application delegate is to provide methods to control the application lifecycle.

Why do you want a handy way to access the application delegate? I'm guessing you're using it as a singleton, a handy place to store application-wide properties. Don't. Look at each property and decide what you want to do with it. Some may belong together. But in my experience, AppDelegate becomes a dumping ground for attributes that have nothing to do with UIApplication lifecycle management.

Instead, find ways to extract cohesive units.